# Removing array item from session in CakePHP

Tags: arrays, session, cakephp

I've added an array (shopping cart) into session. Now to remove an item from cart, I tried this logic. The cart is working fine and I can see all the items from the cart on my page. The removing logic is not giving me any error but also not removing the item from session.

What am I doing wrong?

```
function addToCart(){

    $this->layout = false;
    $this->render(false);

    $cart = array();

    $tempcart = unserialize($this->Session->read("cart")); 

    if(isset($tempcart)){
        $cart = $tempcart;
    }

    $productId = $this->request->data("id");

    if(!$this->existsInCart($cart, $productId)){

        $cart[] = array("productId" => $productId, "createdAt" => date());

        $this->Session->write("cart", serialize($cart));

        echo "added";
    }
    else
        echo "duplicate";
}


function removeFromCart(){

    $this->layout = false;
    $this->render(false);

    $cart = array();

    $tempcart = unserialize($this->Session->read("cart"));

    if(isset($tempcart)){
        $cart = $tempcart;
    }

    $productId = $this->request->data("productId");

    for($i=0;$i<count($cart);$i++){

        $cartItem = $cart[$i];   //  an array

        if($cartItem["productId"]==$productId)
            unset($cart[$i]);
    }

    $this->Session->write("cart", serialize($cart));

    echo "removed";
}
```

Comment: are you getting some values in $productId?? or is it $id??

Comment: @KuldeepChoudhary Smart catch!

Comment: Actually in table it is **id**, i'm clicking on a product and sending the value of id in **productId**. Its working as I checked in google chrome developer tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not updating the session with the correct value

```
function removeFromCart() {
    $this->layout = false;
    $this->render(false);

    $productId = $this->request->data("productId");

    // make sure this is the value you need
    debug($productId);

    $tempCart = unserialize($this->Session->read("cart"));
    if (!empty($tempCart)) {
        for ($i=0; $i<count($tempCart); $i++) {
            if ($tempCart[$i]["productId"] == $productId) {
                unset($tempCart[$i]);
            }
        }
        $this->Session->write("cart", serialize($tempCart));
    }

    echo "removed";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$productId = $this->request->data("productId");
```

Are you sure you want to write "productId" instead of "id"?

You seem to have sent "id" in the request during add-to-cart, possibly you are doing the same while deleting.

Also, you have your cart saved in `$cart`, so you need to serialize `$cart` and not `$newcart`.

So your remove from cart code becomes:

```
function removeFromCart(){

    $this->layout = false;
    $this->render(false);

    $cart = array();

    $tempcart = unserialize($this->Session->read("cart"));

    if(isset($tempcart)){
        $cart = $tempcart;
    }

    $productId = $this->request->data("id");

    for($i=0;$i<count($cart);$i++){

        $cartItem = $cart[$i];   //  an array

        if($cartItem["productId"]==$productId)
            unset($cart[$i]);
    }

    $this->Session->write("cart", serialize($cart));

    echo "removed";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why you aren't using just [delete()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html#SessionComponent%3a%3adelete) function of session component ?

```
$this->Session->delete('cart');
```